# Update Postgres table with array elements

Tags: php, postgresql

I want update the Postgres database table with array elements but I didn't know how.

I tried this but I got this notice: Notice: Undefined index: 'value' in 'file' on line x

**Update:**

```
private function debug ($function_name, $arg_names, $arg_vals (<=with func_get_args())  ) 
{
    $arg_names_array = explode(',', $arg_names);
    foreach($arg_names_array as $k => $v)
    {
        $v = trim($v);
        $v = pg_escape_string($v);
        $vars[$k] = $arg_vals[$v];
    }
    $this->return_ = $vars;
    return $this->return_;  
}
pg_query($connect, "UPDATE tabe SET row = {$vars[$first]}  WHERE code = {$vars[$code]} ");
pg_query($connect, "UPDATE tabe SET row = '{$vars[$first]}'  WHERE code = '{$vars[$code]}' ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need more context information to be able to help you. I understand you want to update a field wich contains an array of values. Remember that in postgresql, the array syntax is {value1,value2,...,valueN}, where value is enclosed in apostrophes if it is a string.

So what does $vars[$first] contain? if it is a php array, you must convert it first to a situable string for the sql command.

Comment: Sorry, the real problem was this:  $var[] = $this->return_ . So, right method is $var = $this->return_.

Comment: Right query: "UPDATE tabe SET row = '{$vars['$first']}'  WHERE code = '{$vars['$code']}' ";